# StartFullScreen() method not working using Phaser-2.4.4

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i am new to game development using Phaser-2.4.4. currently i am working on a game where i need to set full screen mod in my browser. First i create an game object and then call the full screen method it doesn't work at all.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1920, 1080, Phaser.AUTO, '', {preload : preload,create :create, update : update});
```

`game.scale.startFullScreen();`

error is

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
Phaser.ScaleManager: requestFullscreen failed or device does not support the Fullscreen API
```

please help and let me know what i am missing.

Comment: Could you provide minimal working example of your problem i.e. on jsfiddle? It cannot be  deduced where do you call startFullScreen(), what is your render target etc. . Also, what browser/device are you testing your solution on?

Comment: I agree with Krystian providing a code snippet is more easier to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because you can't trigger fullscreen without user interaction. The snippet of code that actually says "go fullscreen" must be the result of the user clicking something (anything).

This is a browser limitation, not a Phaser issue.

I would suggest following standard practice and placing a "go fullscreen" button so the user has a choice

Comment: thanks i figure this out there should be an input from user to trigger this. now i want to to disable the "Esc" button the exit the full screen. i want to run my game in full screen mood . once it is triggered it will not exit until end.
how can achieve that as I know exit behavior is from API how can i tackle it???

Comment: You should mark this question/answer as complete (for future readers) and open a new question to tackle your new inquiry

Comment: @GulZaibAmjed If this is a browser based game you should not be forcing the fullscreen until the game has exited - it goes against one of the primary things that the HTML5 medium is trying to achieve by moving away from head strong plugins that take control of the client machine. If the user doesn't want fullscreen, that is their choice